# How do I know which molecular structure is glycine's "base state"?

Tags: biochemistry, amino-acids, ph

I was looking up the chemical structure of glycine, and I found the following two images: [image: glycineH2N]

and

[image: glycineH3N].

My question is, what is the "base state", or the "natural state" of glycine? Under what scenarios does glycine become oxidized/reduced?

Also, I know that amino acids contain a carboxyl group, an amino group, a lone hydrogen atom, and a side chain. What is the formula for the amino group? Is it $\ce{-NH_2}$ or $\ce{-NH_3^+}$?

Comment: Both are correct, both are the natural state of glycine and both represent the base state. Amino acids are zwitterions, which switch freely between the two states. Try googling zwitterions.

Comment: So, they are just different ways of representing the same thing? Is there a "more correct" diagram?

Comment: edited my first comment, try searching for zwitterions.

Comment: If you want to be really specific the forms exist in equilibriums, but may be affected by pH. if the ph I very low, glycine is positively charged, neutrally charged around average pK value for the amine and carboxylic acid groups, while negatively charged at high pH.

Comment: Wait, so the amino group can be represented as either NH2 or NH3+?

Comment: Correct, both are entirely correct. However at physiological pH (6-8), typically the zwitterform with charges are used.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: the second molecule should have a negative charge at the -COO group

Comment: I really think this should be closed. The poster does not define his question properly — there is no such thing as base state — cannot copy the correct structure of the zwitterion form, and is ultimately asking the most basic of questions the answer to which can be found in any text or web resource. In addition it is ultimately chemistry rather than biology.

Comment: Please note that these are acid/base reactions and _not_ oxidation/reduction reactions. If glycine is oxided or reduced its not glycine anymore.

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:** You need to define *base state*.

**Background:** The point to keep in mind here is that the *base state* (as you call it) is not constant. As @jeppenielsen points out in the comments, amino acids are zwitterions. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion):

> In chemistry, a zwitterion, formerly called a dipolar ion, is a neutral molecule with both positive and negative electrical charges. (In some cases multiple positive and negative charges may be present.) Zwitterions are sometimes called inner salts. Unlike simple amphoteric compounds that may only form either a cationic or anionic species, a zwitterion simultaneously has both ionic states.

In glycine, the center of positive charge is the -NH<sub>2</sub> group while the center of negative charge is the -COOH group. At different pH (acidic, neutral or basic), the structure of the molecule keeps on changing as shown in the image below:

[image: glycine structure at different pH][source](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/motm/glycine/glycineh.htm)

Structure of other amino acids also changes similarly. To know why this change occurs, just keep in mind that (in very simple terms) pH is inversely proportional to the concentration of H<sup>+</sup> ions in a solution (higher the pH, lower the concentration of H<sup>+</sup>). The exact formula is $\ce{pH = - log[H_3O^+]}$ (yes, it means that a pH of 4 is 10 times more acidic than pH 5 and so on). Also, as pH changes, so does the formula for the amino group (see the diagram again).

Comment: Good answer, as always, but this is incorrect: *"keep in mind that pH is inversely proportional to the concentration of H+ ions"*. The bigger the pH the lower the H+ ions concentration, that's correct... However, *inversely proportional* has another meaning in math: it means that the multiplication of the two variables is a constant. And that is clearly not the case here, do the math and you'll see. Actually, you can have a variable growing while the other one decreases and still they can be *directly proportional*!

Comment: That was a simplification, thats why I also put the formula with it. But I'll change it if it seems incorrect :) seems better now?

Comment: Kind of. Just say that "the higher the pH the lower the H+ concentration".

Comment: or say pH=-log(H+) and do it correctly. ah I see it was added alredy.

Comment: @jeppenielsen thanks! There is a post on chemistry.SE (whose link I am unable to find right now) which discusses about why it is better to write $\ce{H_3O^+}$ instead of $\ce{H^+}$ :)

Comment: H3O+ only works if you use water as solvent... you could use ammonia as a solvent and H+ would still work. Or you could be in a nonpolar solvent. H+ only fails in heavy water, but then we should be writing pD instead anyways

Comment: @jeppenielsen since we're talking about it in biological perspective, we can assume water to be the solvent ;)

Comment: Not in the lipid bilayer of the cellmembranes.

Comment: @jeppenielsen Do you expect free (polar/charged) glycine to be found in the (hydrophobic) cell membrane? I don't...

Comment: Only in extremely low concentration.  But using pH=-log([H3O+]) instead of [H+] is silly especially since we have general notaion for all solvents. Also [H+] is significantly different than [H3O+] in some cases.

Comment: Thats why I was talking about that chemistry.SE post. It clearly talks about why we use H3O+ instead of H+. In short, H+ is too unstable to exist and readily reacts with any nearby molecule. Mostly it forms H3O+, but it can also form H5O2+, H7O3+ and even H9O4+. So, once you know what is actually happening at the concerned scale, writing H+ becomes a lot more silly.